# Directly return a table entry from a (simplest) function in Lua

Tags: lua, coding-style, return-value, lua-table

I wanted to write the simplest possible function which let me return the desired value in a nameless table and, *ideally*, it should be something like this:

```
function RL_MyTool:Version(n)
    return {"0.4.0", "20221003-0230", "13.5.5"}[n]
end
```

But, of course, that's not allowed in Lua...

---

So, off the top of my head, I can think on these two other possibilities:

**1:**

```
function RL_MyTool:Version(n)
    local t = {"20221003-0230", "13.5.5"}
    return t[n] or "0.4.0"
end
```

**2:**

```
function RL_MyTool:Version(n)
    local n, t = n or 1, {"0.4.0", "20221003-0230", "13.5.5"}
    return t[n]
end
```

Both of them slightly different from each other but doing the same, counting with the advantage of returning a default value if no argument is given, which is good. BUT... Do you think I could still have a possibility of writing it like in the very simplest fashion way above? Basically, **what I'd like is not even have to use a single variable or table declaration along the function** but still let me return the specified table entry when called.

Well, that's all. Of course if it's finally not possible (as I'm afraid) it won't be the end of the world , but I wanted to be sure I wasn't missing any Lua *trick* or something that let me do it more like I firstly imagined... Thanks!

P.S. Oh, I don't see how, but of course if it could be achieved without the necessity of even using a table at all, that would be equally valid or even better.

---

**EDIT:** BTW, for the record and based in @Piglet (great!) answer, I got to reduce it even more this way:

```
function RL_MyTool:Version(n)
    return ({"0.4.0", "20221003-0230", "13.5.5"})[n or 1]
end
```

Improving code usability/maintenance a bit at the same time by avoiding duplicated values... Kind of a win-win-win

Comment: You should drag the table out of the function to avoid recreating it (which creates a table which immediately becomes garbage after the func is done with it) with every function call.

Comment:  Well, in this case I think I'll leave like that because here I'm also treating to follow a "style" in base of the other official tools, but it  is of course a good recommendation for general cases where normally optimization will take preference... So thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Sounds like a sucky style. I see being able to name the table as an advantage.

Comment: Well, it maybe a little more "complex". In reality, the original tools never used anything like this because they didn't seem to have the necessity of returning more than one element... But I do, because I want to reduce the number of these extra kind of little functions as much as possible (which, BTW, besides being tiny will only run once), and this is the more appropriate way of introducing my change in consonance with the existing ones not having to put too much code on only one line and making them less readable. Hmm, I hope it makes (some) sense...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put the table in parenthesis.

```
function RL_MyTool:Version(n)
    return ({"0.4.0", "20221003-0230", "13.5.5"})[n] or "0.4.0"
end
```

But what is the purpose of this? Code should be easy to read and easy to work on. There is absolutely no reason to not use a local table. You don't have to pay a dollar for each line of code.

Comment: It works! That's EXACTLY the kind of Lua "trick" I was expecting to be missing or something, thanks! Indeed I already had played with several parenthesis combinations because I read in the Lua manual they could be useful for solve certain function multi-return situations, but none of them worked for me in this case, until now :)

Comment: Oh, and the reason is halfway between the aesthetic and the functional (more the first one in this case I must admit ) of the resulting code, but sometimes everything matters, even if it's only for the challenge of reducing to the minimum (and in this case it doesn´t make it more difficult to read, so is a win-win... Hence, thanks again!