# Is there a way I can reduce this in-a-row kind of repeating Lua conditions?

Tags: if-statement, lua, conditional-statements

I think I already could know the answer... but just to be totally sure, sometimes I find myself writing conditionals like:

```
if type(value) ~= "function" and type(value) ~= "table" and type(value) ~= "thread" and type(value) ~= "userdata" then
    --do whatever...
end
```

And every time I wonder if there couldn't be a more economical way to do it, for example, like:

```
if type(value) ~= "function" and ~= "table" and ~= "thread" and ~= "userdata" then
    --do whatever...
end
```

I mean, not having to repeat the whole individual condition all the times since the first part (type(value)) is always going to the same. Of course the above wouldn't work, but could it be any other way I'm simply not seeing? I hope it makes sense...

Comment: I write Lua code on a regular basis, I usually don't need this kind of condition based on types, except on a very few cases. So you might want to check if these conditions are really important or might be dropped... AFAIK, Lua doesn't provide a specific syntax to do what you are asking.

Comment: Well, the "type" condition here was only an example, but it really could be anything... I have ended up with this first-part-repeating row of conditions under all kind of different situations and that's why I finally decided to ask just in case, because sometimes Lua still surprise you with some hidden _trick_ (normally involving parenthesis ). Although, yes... as you point, the most probably here is it's what it is...

Comment: `if not ({["function"]=0,table=0,thread=0,userdata=0})[type(value)] then`

Comment: why not define a function?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Curious! It somehow recalls me to [**THIS**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73966058/2805176) other solution and I'd have never thought about it in this case... It kind of affect legibility (at least until you get used to it), so not sure if it's something I would use in most cases, but I take note about it as a possibility for some of them, thanks!

Comment: @pynexj Thanks. Well that's always a possibility, of course... but sometimes you can simply prefer the linearity that a simple condition offers. But, of course, for more complex sentences I wouldn't doubt it...

Comment: [Related if not dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40035859/16217248)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do it like this. Coming from R, I am used to having the `%in%` function. Below, I create a function that works in a similar way in lua:

```
-- return true if one of the elements of tab is equal to el
local function in_tab(el, tab)

  for _, v in pairs(tab) do
    if el == v then return true end
  end
  return false
end
```

And you can call it like this:

```
if not in_tab(type(object), 
              { "table", "userdata", "thread", "function" }) then ...

end
```

Given how fast `pairs()` is, this does not seem to incur any penalty on the computation time. In addition, it comes in very handy all the time.

Of course, if you keep testing against the same values, a much simpler solution is a simple lookup:

```
local dts = { table = true, userdata = true, thread = true }

if dts[ type(object) ] then ... end
```

Of course, in case of function you would have to do this:

```
dts["function"] = true
```

because neither `{ function = true }` nor `dts.function = true` are allowed.

Comment: You can use `dts = {["function"] = true}` for such cases.

Answer (score 2):

Why not create a function that mimics `isinstance` from Python?

```lua
local function isinstance(obj, ...)
    local obj_type = type(obj)
    for _, v in pairs{...} do
        if v == obj_type:
            return true
    return false
end
```

Usage:

```lua
if not isinstance(value, "function", "table", "thread", "userdata") then
    -- do whatever...
end
```

You may even want to add additional functionality like matching the "type" based on the metatable or disambiguating integers and floats.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about it and I liked the idea of mimic such function. Sincerely, I didn't expect to have to resort to a function when I asked this question (I was more looking for something like a syntactic _trick_ to simply reduce a little the condition length or such, but since there seems not to be another way, I may end up applying the function solution for more complex cases and the direct table one from the other answers for the more simplest. If anything new arises, I think I'll choose January's answer since it seems to include all the possibilities, but (again) thanks!